# Antonym of 'sample' ('example')

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is the antonym of the adjective "sample" (example/specimen) besides "whole"? I'd like to replace "non-sample" in the following sentence:

> I saved my *sample* code but accidentally deleted my *non-sample* project.

Comment: Not exactly an English thing, but... how many people on this site can program?

Comment: @user7834 program a VCR? ;)

Comment: @compman: I'd say, in reference to the Shapiro-Wharf hypothesis, all of us :D

Comment: @Matt: I'm not following.

Comment: @compman: Well, if you take programming to mean influencing people's behaviour, since all software developers do is influence the behaviour of computers, and since the Shapiro-Whorf hypothesis states that language influence thought, we can all programme each other.

Comment: It seemed funnier earlier...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a similar context, I would tend to use **actual** or **real**:

> I saved my *example* code but accidentally deleted my *real* code.
>   I saved my *sample* code but accidentally deleted my *actual* code.

These contrast well with *example*, *sample*, *mock*, or *pseudo-*, but sound best when you're expressing that contrast on a particular noun (*sample code…actual code*); it sounds awkward if the distinction isn't stressed (*sample code…actual project*).

Answer (score 2):

What about **entire**? Or **finished**? Perhaps it depends on what you want to express.

Comment: I have two types of code: *sample* and *non-sample*, where the sample code does not have to be a subset of the non-sample code. "finished" might be closer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The code used in actual products is often called “production code.”

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for [**test** vs. **control** groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_control)? or experimental sample vs. control sample?

> An experiment which uses controls is
>   called a "controlled experiment", and
>   usually separates research subjects
>   into two groups: an experimental group
>   and a control group. The control group
>   is practically identical to the
>   experimental group, although the
>   experimental group is changed
>   according to some key variable of
>   interest, while the control group
>   remains constant during the
>   experiment. Each field develops their
>   own specific, important controls.